# Travelling Salesman Problem Easy Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman

I'm looking for a easier algorithm to implement to solve the travelling salesman problem (in javascript). 
Unluckily all of the ones i found are really hard to understand/ to implement.

The ones i already have are the nearest/farthest-neighbour-algorithms. Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: Please name a few of those you found hard to understand, with a unique identification of the main resources you used to understand each. Do you insist on *best solution* or are you willing to settle for *acceptable*?

Comment: For example Branch-and-Cut and Branch-and-Bound were hard andi would like to get a best solution.

Comment: If you want a "best solution" and an easy to understand one, you probably just want to consider all possible paths (all possible permutations of your n nodes). This probably won't solve instances over n=11 or 12 nodes, mind you.

Comment: oof, thats unlucky because i need an algorithm for 16 nodes ._. maybe do you know an easy acceptable solution algorithm expect the ones i mentioned?

Comment: The $O(2^n)$ dynamic programming is quite simple and probably fast enough for 16 nodes. It is documented in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: @saltea, there positively *is no* easy algorithm for that problem for any definition of the word "easy", except if you really trivialize it (i.e. with the sketch provided in vonbrand's answer, or by just trying like 20 random permutations and picking the quickest one...).

Comment: @saltea, Maybe ask a different question where you explain where you had problems with the algorithms you've found, and try to solve those...

Comment: @AnoE: generating all permutations is not especially difficult. And computing the cycle length is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

It is an *extremely* hard problem to solve. But some reasonable heuristics are easy to explain/code.

One is to start at a random vertex, each step move to the vertex that hasn't been visited yet that is closest. Rinse and repeat.

Another is to start with a minimal spanning tree of the graph, pick any vertex as starting point (root), and visit the vertices in preorder. If you are asked to visit a vertex that you already visited, just skip it for the next one in preorder. Think about it as walking along the "outside" of the tree, taking shortcuts to the next when asked to visit a vertex again. This works rather well if the distances have the triangular property (i.e., $c(u v) \le c(u x) + c(x v)$ for all vertices).

See if you can come up with another idea.

Comment: But the OP seems to want an exact algorithm based on the comments.

Comment: Good luck with that. Does he want it in polynomial time as well?

Comment: @gnasher729 Sorry I had missed your comment earlier. Notice that there's only at most 16 nodes.

Comment: Why do you say *extremely hard* ? The problem statement is easy, a brute force solution is easy. Even a solution by simulated annealing is easy.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a trivial algorithm running in n! .  That would be good enough for n=12. N=16 would talk about 43,000 times longer - probably just outside what you’d call a solution. Here’s a method that should save you just enough time to solve for n=16:

Take a sub tour abcd. If the distance abcd is longer than the distance acbd then abcd cannot be part of an optimal tour (since swapping b and c creates a shorter tour). If both sub tours have the same length we can arbitrarily exchange b and c if b is later in the alphabet than c. So we accept exactly half of the subsequences in an attempt to find an optimal tour.

Now we pick any fixed city b as the second city. We don’t need to try different cities as the second city because we can rotate the tour. We then pick any a and c as the first and third city, picking their order so that a comes before c in the alphabet. There are 15 x 14 / 2 = 105 choices for these three cities.

Then we choose the fourth city d. But instead of 13 choices, the requirement that abcd is not longer than acbd removes on average half the choices, so 6.5 on average. For cities 15 and 16 there is only one choice.

Total choices for the order of all cities is 15! / 2^13 ≈ 160,000,000. You’ll need to implement this in an efficient way. For general n, it is (n-1)! / 2^(n-3).

You could improve this by choosing which sequences abcde are possible. B, c and d can be visited in six different orders, and only one can be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force is not that difficult. All you need to do is to generate all permutations of a vector `(0, 1, ... n-1)` and compute the length of the corresponding cycle.

To generate the permutations, consider the input vector, extract one element at a time and recurse on the remaining elements.

E.g.

```
Permute(0, 1, 2, 3) ->
 0 + Permute(1, 2, 3),
 1 + Permute(0, 2, 3), 
 2 + Permute(0, 1, 3), 
 3 + Permute(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: There are ways to consider permutations that differ in one swap of adjacent elements, only, e.g. [(Steinhaus–)Johnson–Trotter(–Even)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm#Even%27s_speedup): The cost for a tour *head→a→b→tail* can be updated to the next tour *head→b→a→tail* by *subtracting the former arrows and adding the new* - **independent of tour length**.

Comment: @greybeard: right. I gave the most "obvious" approach.

Comment: To make this likely much faster, sort the cities so that city 2 is closest to city 1, c3 closest to c2 etc. And stop when a tour so far is longer than the shortest tour found.

Comment: @gnasher729: in the world of exponential algorithms, "much faster" means "that can handle marginally bigger problems". :-)

Comment: True. But if a van driver can go to at most 15 places in a day, “marginally bigger” may be all you need.